# Insufficient permissions while pushing local branch to remote

Tags: git, github, permissions

So I've cloned a master repo to my local machine, and the made a new branch like this:

git checkout -b branchname

Then I've made an initial commit, and made some change inside of a project. After that I've committed those changes locally. So, now I want to push them to the remote.

When I do something like:

`git push origin branchname`

I get this error:

> error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository
>   database ./objects
>
> fatal: failed to write object error: unpack failed: unpack-objects
>   abnormal exit

as well as this one:

> error: failed to push some refs to "blah blah (path of a project on my
>   server)".

Unlike this, if I try to push some other projects to the remote, it is working. Or at least it worked the last time I tried (I can check this as well, but it worked normally for the last few days).

What permissions I need to push this new branch to the remote?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Gerrit?

We sometimes encounter the similar problems. Totally unpredictable, unable to reproduce. We call it 'unpack error'. I find a solution to push successfully, though the root cause is still unknown.

Suppose the git repo with unpack error is at /foo/.git

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
git init
git fetch /foo/  HEAD
git push <remote> FETCH_HEAD:<remote_branch>
```

Comment: Well I am not on Gerrit. The problem was with file owner. It was silly. This solved the issue : sudo chown -R myusername myprojectname/